# Is there any iOS offline maps app which also supports searching for an address offline?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, maps

Is there any iOS map app that works completely without WiFi/3G connection and supports (at a minimum) viewing your current location (on GPS-equipped iOS devices) and searching for an address? My intended use case scenario is mostly navigating around on foot in a foreign city.

I tried [Navfree](http://www.navmii.com/) but it seems to require a data connection to search for an address (and is also mostly meant for car navigation). I didn't try [Galileo](http://galileo-app.com/) yet, but the website only mentions “online search” for the free version; it's not clear whether the paid version features offline search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers to this question and related questions on this site, I found and wound up trying three different offline map apps which also support offline search. All three offer the basic features of downloading maps for a certain region, viewing your current location and searching for nearby street names and points of interest. In addition, OffMaps 2 and City Maps 2Go also feature downloadable Wikipedia articles for the points of interest on each map. Offmaps 2 can also show a public transport network overlay on top of the regular map.

- [MapsWithMe Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/app/mapswithme-pro/id510623322): €3.99 for the app, no extra charges per map.
- [OffMaps 2](http://itunes.apple.com/app/offmaps-2/id403232367): €0.79 for the app, includes 2 free maps; €0.79 per pack of 3 extra maps or €4.99 for unlimited maps. Each map includes Wikipedia articles (optional download) and a public transport overlay.
- [City Maps 2Go](http://itunes.apple.com/app/city-maps-2go/id327783342): €1.59 for the app, no extra charges per map. Enabling the Wikipedia articles download option is an additional one-time €2.39 charge. (*)

Based upon first impressions, the one I would recommend is City Maps 2Go. The public transport overlay of OffMaps 2 is an interesting additional feature, but I prefer City Maps 2Go's cleaner interface. I also already experienced several app crashes with OffMaps 2. MapsWithMe Pro seems comparatively expensive.

(*) The app appears to be designed to charge a separate fee for enabling this option for each map, but currently has an “Introduction offer: buy ‘Wiki Plus’ now and you will get lifetime, global, unlimited download rights.”

Answer (score 3):

[MapsWithMe](http://www.mapswithme.com) does that. Available for iPhone/iPad and Android. [MapsWithMe Pro for iPhone](http://www.mapswithme.com/iphone-app-pro) has offline search. Not an address search though, i.e. you can search for a street, city, restaurant or POI, but not for city+street or street+POI.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question; yes, there is an app which will provide you with offline maps.

There is [OpenMaps](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/openmaps-free/id359719250?mt=8) (my favorite). Here you can download your maps online (when you're at home) and when you're offline, you can make a route to a pinpoint you've created. It will calculate the route by itself. And it's free too.

And, if you've jailbroken your iPhone, you can install [Offline Maps.](http://www.htmlremix.com/iphone/offline-map-in-iphone) Which will pretty much to the same as OpenMaps.

Comment: As you say you're only answering the first part of my question, does that mean OpenMaps doesn't have a search feature or requires a data connection for it to work? Edit: ah, never mind, I see the iTunes store page says “Features: Search online for a location.”